# Fix width of drop down menu in select box option

Tags: html, css, angular5

I am using Angular5 for front-end development. I am trying with css but not getting any solution. Here is picture bellow. I want a solution that will be used Ellipsis for overflow text in dropdown boxes.
![] https://i.stack.imgur.com/fylO6.png

```
         <div class="col-3 form-group d-flex">
            <label>Air</label>
            <select>
               <option>One - A long option that gets cut off</option>
               <option>Two - A long option that gets cut off</option>
            </select>
        </div>


    select {
           width: 100%; 
           overflow: hidden; 
           text-overflow: ellipsis;
         }
```

Comment: Try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to your `select`.

Comment: I did not see any good solution for this, you have to use custom select to make your attach effect.

Comment: This is still not working

Answer (score 0):

As explain here : [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

It is not directly/natively possible. You need to use JS libraries, that will "fake" the `<select>` with other HTML elements.

> The `<select>` element's internal structure is complex, and hard to control. If you want to get full control, you should consider **using a library** with good facilities for styling form widgets, or try rolling your own dropdown menu using non-semantic elements, JavaScript, and WAI-ARIA to provide semantics.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Styling_with_CSS